# How to post json in cURL with file

Tags: json, curl, post, lua

I'm trying to post json using cURL in Lua and attach multipart file. Tried in following way, but it do not work:

```
local cURL = require "cURL"

c = cURL.easy{
  url        = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
  post       = true,
  httpheader = {
    "Content-Type: application/json";
  };
  postfields = "{}";
}

c:setopt_httppost(curl.form()
                 :add_file('file', recording_filename, 'audio/mp4',
                       filename..'.mp4', {'Content-length: ' .. fileSize}
             ))

c:perform()
```

Any help will be highly appreciable! Thank you!

Comment: I was wrong json data is attached as HTML file, I'll try to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect to use `application/json` for posting files. You haveto use `multipart/form-data` everytime while posting a file in any languages or library.

For your case , I would usggest to use this example:

https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv2/blob/master/examples/post.lua

```
local cURL = require("cURL")

c = cURL.easy_init()

c:setopt_url("http://localhost")
postdata = {  
   -- post file from filesystem
   name = {file="post.lua",
       type="text/plain"},
   -- post file from data variable
   name2 = {file="dummy.html",
        data="<html><bold>bold</bold></html>",
        type="text/html"}}
c:post(postdata)
c:perform()

stream_postdata = {
   -- post file from private read function
   name = {file="stream.txt",
        stream_length="5",
        type="text/plain"}}

count = 0
c:post(stream_postdata)
c:perform({readfunction=function(n)
               if (count < 5)  then
                  count = 5
                  return "stream"
               end
               return nil
            end})
print("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I need to add json info for this request. How I can do this? The point is that I need to send file with some info inside json.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` means you can add as much elements as you  wish. for example , create the other `name_json = ... `  with json data inside